# How to highlight an entire row in Excel when a change to a cell is made using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, row, highlight

I have a formula that will highlight a cell if something is changed in excel (below) but I wanted to see if I could tweek it a little and make the entire row highlight yellow if a cell is changed? Any ideas?

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Target.Interior.Color = vbYellow
End Sub
```

Comment: `Target.EntireRow.Interior.Color`? It might have been easier and faster to try this yourself than to spend the time writing a question ;-) Though... by "entire row" do you mean literally the entire row, or just the cells in the row with data?

Comment: Also keep in mind, that this will make the color of the row permanent. Once macro has been executed and found “True”, it will be colored yellow. Changing the value again will not change the color back; you may want to add some code to address this as well.

Comment: Thanks BigBen & Havard!